# RDLC rendering performance (ASP.Net)

Tags: asp.net, rdlc, report-viewer2010

I have RDLC report that uses list with ~200K records as object data source. Records are grouped by one field and report is splitted into pages. When I trying to test it - it takes about 4 minutes to render report. Profiler shows that data source generation takes 1 minute and 3 minutes are taken by CreateSnapshot method from report viewer OnPreRender event. It looks like reporting services renders report body for whole report to determine total page count and then shows only first page. Is there way to fix such behavior somehow? If it wouldn't show exact total page count for user - I am OK with it.

Comment: Are you showing 200K rows grouped or you also aggregate this information? How many pages are generated?

Answer (score 1):

I have found that having expressions in RDLC reports hurts performance, this is especially said for expressions to group on or sort on.

Eliminating all expressions might bring down the processing time to seconds instead of minutes.